# Asp.net core MVC make action optional in routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

Im trying to manage my routing settings for my projet but I don't understand everything, I want to make some actions or controllers names optional in the url.

For example I have a controller "HomeController" with a "SignIn()" action, I want it to be reachable with the url "/signin" and not "/home/signin".

Same for a controller named "ProjectsController" with an action "Details(int id)", I want it to be reachable with "/projects/348" and not "/projects/details/348".

I didn't modify the default endpoint configuration:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

How can I make some controllers name and actions name optional ? And after that will I be able to still use tag helpers for links with asp-controller and asp-action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use route attributes. For example for your SignIn action

```
    public partial class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("~/signin")]
        public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
            .....
        }
    }
```

and use the same template for another special actions

and you can have several routes for one action  too

```
        [Route("~/signin")]
        [Route("~/home/signin")]
        public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
            .....
        }
```

Comment: Does the route attribute override the endpoint configuration in startup.cs ?

Comment: the route attributesdosn' t effect endpoints. The route attributes have the highest priority. Only if action doesn' t  have routed attributes, than endpoints route is used.